# How to migrate an existing database to Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm

The steps I am currently attempting are shown below:

---

1 Create XML from database using the existing database in bootstrap.

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database xml ./config/xml
```

2 Create classes from entities:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities -vvv ./src
```

3 Create the schema (bootstrap is modified to use a new database):

```
vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

4 Compare the two schemas.

---

Is this the correct process?  Any missing steps?  Should I be using `orm:generate-proxies` and `orm:generate-repositories` at this stage?  How would you recommend comparing the schema's?  Where is `orm:convert:mapping` namespace option used?

Thank you